# Estou tentando fazer um botão de favorito no react js, que ao clicar no ícone com a className"far fa-heart" ele mude para className"fas fa-heart"

Tags: javascript, css, react-hooks

```
import Cama from 'cama.png'
import React from 'react'
import styles from './styles.module.scss'

export default function Recommend() {

    const [favorit, setFavorit ] = useState();

    
    return (
        <div className={styles.cardContext}>
            <div>
            <p><i  className="far fa-heart" id="item"></i></p>

                <img src={Cama} alt="Cama" />
            </div>
         </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem algumas maneiras de fazer isso, seguindo o que você estava fazendo ficaria assim:

```
import Cama from "cama.png";
import React from "react";
import styles from "./styles.module.scss";

export default function Recommend() {
  const [favorite, setFavorite] = useState(false);

  // Confere pra ver se o valor do estado está como "true"
  // Se estiver ele retorna a classe com o coração preenchido
  const checkIfIsFavorite = () => (favorite ? "fas fa-heart" : "far fa-heart");

  // Altera o "favorite" para o contrário ao ser executada
  const handleToggleFavorite = () => setFavorite((previous) => !previous);

  return (
    <div className={styles.cardContext}>
      <div>
        <p onClick={handleToggleFavorite}>
          <i className={checkIfIsFavorite} id="item"></i>
        </p>
        <img src={Cama} alt="Cama" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```